# When comeback to activity after taking image from camera application is close and open in Android

Tags: android

My application was close immediately when come back after taking image from camera and again restart the application automatically immediately.Why does happen with camera.

Here is my Camera code.

```
btnCamera = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_Camera);
            btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
                    String picformat = strVesselId + "_" + s.format(new Date()) + ".jpeg";

                    //Log.e(" picformat ", " = " + picformat);

                    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                    String path = baseDir + "/classnkk_images/";

                    editor.putString("AddImagePath", path);
                    editor.putString("picformat",picformat);
                    editor.commit();

                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "classnkk_images";
                    File myPath = new File(extr, picformat);
                    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(myPath));
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                   // Log.e("Camera", " Open");


                }
            });
```

Here is onActivityResult method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try
        {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST)
            {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

                String getPicFormat = sharedPreferences.getString("picformat", "");
                insertImageAudioList.add(getPicFormat);
                imageSize.add(getPicFormat);

                String baseDir =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                String path = baseDir + "/classnkk_images/"+getPicFormat;
                File file = new File(path);

                fileName.add(file.getAbsolutePath());

                gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
                gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
}
```

Comment: you are facing this problem on any specific device ? or facing problem on all devices ?

Comment: Right now I'm testing the app only one device since 4 months , I'm not try to yet other device.

Comment: Okay. You should try on other device as well. Because it may be device specific issue. And please let me know that which device you are using right now ?

Comment: Some images getting immediately and display it on grid-view , and for some images application was close immediately when come back after taking image from camera and again restart the application automatically immediately.

Comment: Device name is YUPHORIA